# Extending the class definition upon including a file inside its block

Tags: c++, class, include

I am drafting some modification on a C++ I have been given. In order to separate my contributions for the time being, I would like to extend the class definition in a original header file by including another file.

In terms of pseudo code it would be something like this

```
class OldClass : public OldSuperClass
{
  private:
    blah blah
  protected:
    blah blah
  public:
    blah blah
    #include "NewStuff.h" // this is the action
    blah blah
};
```

This was inspired by the explanation that

> the #include directive causes the preprocessor to include another file, usually a header file" (C++ Pocket Reference, O'Reilly).

The file NewStuff contains vanilla definitions like

```
#ifndef _JNew_
#define _JNew_

#include <iomanip>  // this is the mistake (see comments and answers)

const int apha = 1;
double beta;
blah blah

inline double HalfDif (double a, double b)
{
  return (a - b) * 0.5;
}

#endif
```

I would want these to become public members of OldClass. At compile time, however, I receive errors of the type

> error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘namespace’

Searching across the internet fora, these seem to indicate that there is a syntax problem with braces and semicolons.
However, in this case the error is triggered by the inclusion, and I am not familiar with the rules that I have apparently infringed.

What is wrong with the action above, and how can it be made to work? As a temporary hack would actually be quite handy.

Comment: You're putting `#include <iomanip>` inside a class definition.

Comment: You can include your files in middle of class, whith correct syntax. BUT you can't include external includes in your file, since they intended to be used in global scope, not inside class definition.

Comment: I don't see the point of this. If you use a version control system you can keep track of your own changes without resorting to hacks.

Comment: the way you have choosen can work, but I would strongly suggest you to use a version control system instead

Comment: _As a temporary hack would actually be quite handy._ ...but you may not underestimate the life-time of written code and such hacks make the maintenance of S/W a nightmare (sooner or later). (Not that there are better solutions for this issue - like e.g. a version control system like already mentioned. Why do you think git became such popular?) ;-)

Comment: To the commentators above. I am using a version control system already: i want to have all changes in one file as a temporary hack.

Comment: its not clear how you plan to have all modifications in one file. You are modifying the public interface of the class, so most likely also users of the class need to be updated for your modifications to have any effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done can work. Just consider that `#include`s are simply about textual replacement. What you can put in the header is for example:

```
 // xy.h
 int x;
```

So when it is expanded in:

```
struct foo {
    #include "xy.h"
};
```

The result becomes

```
struct foo {
    // xy.h
    int x;
};
```

Your code is invalid after replacing the `#include` with the contents of the header.

However, even if you fix that, this is uncommon and will make a good surprise for many reading the code (real life: surprises yeah, coding: surprises meh). Headers are not made to be used like this. At least use a different extension like `.incl`. But even then it is not a "nice" solution. It will result in a mess pretty fast once you have to apply modifications in different places in the code. If you want to keep your modifications apart from the rest of the code you should use a version control system where you can create your working branch without disturbing others working on other branches.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I am fully aware of the limitations of this hack indeed. The tip of changing the file extension is definitely good. I am already using git and am working on my own branch, so nobody will be bothered by this hack. At this moment I seem to enjoy having a compact view of all the features I am developing. The distinction between surprises in life and coding gives an added philosophical value worth thinking about while hacking away.

Comment: @XavierStuvw glad that you like the note about surprises ;). "good practise" and "bad practice" isn't something to follow blindly. You have to know when to apply what, be aware of the implications and be prepared to maintain the code. From what I know, I still would not go this way, but what you do with the answer is your buisness :P

Comment: The answer had deserved two upvotes. The second one would have been about that separation between "what can work" and "what is expected". Many a commentator jump on the latter, while a question is on the former.